# Drawing arrows using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I am trying to make a small chart and drawing arrows between tcolorbox, using tikz and the 'remember as' tool.

My code is this

```
    \begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, overlay, width=1.5in, halign = flush center, remember as=ci]
Circuit Imprimé
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, overlay, width=2in, halign = flush center, remember as=adm]
Analyse des matériaux
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=1mm,draw=red!75!black]
\draw[->] (ci.east) to (adm.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this
[image]

But you guess that it's not good, and I want to have an arrow that goes horizontal right, the down, then horizontal left (hope it's easy to picture or I'll draw one on paint if you want)

Thanks

EDIT: I managed to give it a specific path using this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=1mm,draw=red!75!black]
\draw[->] (ci.east) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1.5) -- (adm.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives me this
[image]

But 2 problems: the first is I want put the 'y' value so that the last part of the arrow will be horizontal, right now I am just guessing the values of the trajectory. Secondly, is it possible to round the angles of the arrow, sharp angles don't look very good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm without a computer at the moment,  but try this:

```
\draw[->, rounded corners] (ci.east) -- ++(1.5,0)  |- (adm.east);
```

You can change the roundness like `rounded corners=3mm`, or more.

Comment: Hey that's really cool, it works great. Can I just ask you what does the command "|-" does?

Comment: @Dorian it's a TikZ operator.  It draws a vertical line first and a horizontal line after that stopping perpendicular at the last node or coordinate and then drawing the path to it.